# How do I setup a reverse DNS entry in Plesk 9.2.2 frontent?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I need to get a reverse DNS entry into my zones file for one of my domains hosted under Plesk 9.2.2. Does anybody have ANY idea how this done? If all else fails I will have to update the zones file myself, but I am not sure how that will affect the front end working.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just add the necessary PTR records for the domain's DNS zone.

Comment: Not is Plesk. The the frontend limits the PTR record entries.